# Looking for an mp3/mp4 player

Tags: mp3-player

So I've been googling for a while but I can't seem to find an mp3 player device that satisfies my requirements. I need something like an iPod Touch but not an iPod touch (not a big fan of Apple). My requirements are:

1. Can play mp3 for a long time without charge (25 hrs +).
2. Can display mp3 files with a variety of tags (artist, composers, genres, playlists, etc..).
3. Has an internal memory of at least 128GB OR can support a microSD card up to at least 128GB.
4. Must have bluetooth.
5. As for the price I would like if it could be less than 350 euros but if your find something more expensive feel free to recommend it as well.

What I don't care about: Display quality, camera quality, anything that concerns the video basically. I'm looking for a device primarily for mp3, but it needs to have a display and a GUI though.

So, any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't know anyone even still made these as standalone devices.  Have you considered just purchasing an older-model used phone and not connecting services? It might actually cost less.

Comment: Get iPod Classic.  Install Rockbox.  Done.